# `__init__.py ` does not work and results in ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, sys.path

I'm trying to get python to recognize packages without using `sys.path.append()`

Here's how the directory looks like after adding `__init__.py` to every subdir

```
├── Config
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── augmentation_options.py
│   ├── beverly_hills.txt
│   ├── coco.txt
│   ├── set_annotation_conf.py
│   ├── voc_conf.json
│   ├── yolo3.cfg
│   └── yolo4.cfg
├── Data
│   ├── Photos
│   ├── TFRecords
│   ├── XML\ Labels
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── bh_labels.csv
├── Docs
│   ├── Augmentor.md
│   ├── Evaluator.md
│   ├── Predictor.md
│   ├── Trainer.md
│   └── __init__.py
├── Helpers
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   └── utils.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── anchors.py
│   ├── annotation_parsers.py
│   ├── augmentor.py
│   ├── dataset_handlers.py
│   ├── scratch
│   │   └── label_coordinates.csv
│   ├── utils.py
│   └── visual_tools.py
├── LICENSE
├── Logs
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── session.log
├── Main
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   └── models.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── detector.py
│   ├── evaluator.py
│   ├── models.py
│   └── trainer.py
├── Models
│   └── __init__.py
├── Output
│   ├── Data
│   ├── Detections
│   ├── Evaluation
│   ├── Plots
│   └── __init__.py
├── README.md
├── Samples
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── anchors.png
│   ├── anchors_sample.png
│   ├── aug1.png
│   ├── data.png
│   ├── detections.png
│   ├── eval.png
│   ├── map.png
│   ├── pr.png
│   ├── sample_image.png
│   └── true_false.png
├── __init__.py
└── requirements.txt
```

When I try this:

```
% cd Main
% python3 models.py
```

`models.py` imports from `Helpers.utils` so, I get the usual error:

```
emadboctor@MacBook-Pro Main % python3 models.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "models.py", line 23, in <module>
    from Helpers.utils import get_boxes, timer, default_logger, Mish
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Helpers'
```

And nothing really changes this behavior except when I do:(inside models.py and every subdir that contains python modules)

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..')
```

As far as I know the `__init__.py` should have something to do with such troubles or what's the point of `__init__.py` anyway?

And of course any relative imports result in the following error:

in `models.py`:

```
emadboctor@MacBook-Pro Main % python3 models.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "models.py", line 23, in <module>
    from ..Helpers.utils import get_boxes, timer, default_logger, Mish
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
emadboctor@MacBook-Pro Main %
```

Comment: If you don't want to use `sys.append()`, then you need to create `setup.py` file and install the package

Comment: it's not a library or something, it's just a repo and stacking the import statements with `sys.path.append()` in every module looks ugly and pycharm starts complaining about it

Comment: Yes, I konw that ... check out [this link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-running-setup-py.html). By installing your personal project, you will be able to deal with it as if it was an installed package without the need to use `sys.path.append()`. And PyCharm will not complain whatsoever

Comment: So `__init__.py` without being inside a pandas or numpy kind of folder environment is useless I guess